# Spring, XSRF tokens and performance

Tags: spring, security, csrf

I am trying to implement CSRF protection in an existing application. We have Spring MVC on backend and a mix of HTML, CSS and Apache Velocity Templates on frontend.

I have tried configuring the Spring CSRF functionality as shown here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html. After reading through this Spring documentation, I get a feel that after configuration, Spring Security would automatically send tokens with all requests but that is not happening in my case - perhaps something is wrong with my configuration.

As an alternative, I am creating an instance of Spring Security's `CsrfTokenRepository` and calling `generateToken` and `loadToken` methods on it in my front controller which intercepts all HTTP requests coming to the server. This way, I am able to deliver a new token for every HTTP request and then send it back on the next one.

The mechanism fails though if I click different links within my page too frequently - by the time a page is rendered and the new token is set in hidden fields, the browser has already sent a request to another page with an old token. It also fails when I open more than one tab since the token received by the latest opened tab wins over tokens from tabs opened before it.

To overcome this issue, I changed the tokens to be generated only per session. However, now I run the risk of tokens being exposed - via get requests or referrer fields  for example. Is there a way to improve the performance of per request tokens? or make the approach more secure with per session tokens?

Comment: You don't need a token per request (see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22903/why-refresh-csrf-token-per-form-request). Spring Security also does a single one per session. I would strongly suggest to fix your configuration instead of trying to bold things on like this. Add some configuration of spring security (my guess is you haven't configured the security filter chain rendering the security stuff useless).

Comment: Or you could just flag your cookies with the "SameSite" flag to avoid sending them via cross-site requests (more info: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SameSite)

Comment: I have tried this approach to configure Spring Security using XML - docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html‌​5/… - first of all, it does not send tokens, second, it forces me to use Springs's authentication which I do not wish to. How do I tell Spring via XML, that I want to use only the CSRF part?